# RSA decrypt using Openssl error : Public Key operation error

Tags: rsa, attack, openssl

Hello im got stuck at ctf crypto challenge, so at the challenge is given 3 file which is

> `flag.enc pub.key priv.key`

,
so i tried to decrypt using openssl here is my command

> `openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in flag.enc -inkey priv.key`

.
But it get an error with this message
`

> Public Key operation error 40870E30C87F0000:error:0200009F:rsa
> routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding
> error:../crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:269: 40870E30C87F0000:error:02000072:rsa
> routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check
> failed:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:499:`

Maybe my command is wrong, but im confused,  what should i do with the public key?

Comment: You have "padding check failed". This may mean that after applying textbook RSA decryption, the result is not as expected. Look at the [nice manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html) where it mentions RSA padding mode; and perhaps, independently, where it explains how to get a hex dump of the output data. The point is that you learn how to find what to do.